# Print alert() with proper values

Tags: javascript, closures

I was testing closures in ***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqphbhx3/2/).***

The following piece of code prints all the `i` values from `0-9` but in *random order*.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(i);
        }, 2000);
    })(i);
  }
```

How do I overcome this problem, that is print the `i` values in proper order?

The question is not specific to any application/program, but just out of curiosity.

**Update**:

Only happens in *Google Chrome*.

Comment: I don't see your issue and the code is properly formatted to print them in the right order!

Comment: alert show in order for me, are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: @atmd. Yes, it prints in a random order for me. Can you try 2-3 times, if still it prints in correct order than I guess the problem is something else.

Comment: it works well in firefox, it prints in a random order in chrome

Comment: @LuthandoLoot. Just noticed that. Will add that point to the question.

Comment: If you use `console.log(i)` instead of `alert` you will see that it isn't printed in random order, so I think that the problem is from the browser which is displaying the alerts based on the time they were called: most recently will be displayed first and then will continue with the alerts which was not displayed even if they were called earlier

Comment: a similar question was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26540900/4323504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to alert the number each 2000 milliseconds? If so, try this:

```
function printNum(i, max) {
    alert(i);
    if (i == max) return;

    setTimeout(function () {
        printNum(i + 1, max);
    }, 2000);
}

printNum(0, 10);
```

Otherwise, if you want to alert them after 2000 milliseconds one after the other:

```
function printNum(i, max) {
    alert(i);
    if (i == max) return;

    printNum(i + 1, max);
}

setTimeout(function () { printNum(0, 10); }, 2000);
```

Comment: Your second solution is what I wanted. A simple workaround of what I am trying.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, in Chrome it alerts them in random order. I fixed it just by adding `i` to the time, apparently then the alert queue is ordered properly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(i);
        }, 2000+i);
    })(i);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hqphbhx3/5/

Comment: run this 3 or 4 times, it will still go back to random order

Comment: This works. @LuthandoLoot. I ran it many a times. I am getting the proper order.

Comment: @LuthandoLoot. Strange browser problems. May be someting to do with version :)